# How to compare two columns from different sheets and put a value in another sheet? vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 worksheets: WUR, Homologation and read.

I want to read column 1 from "WUR", when i find first value i want to compare with first column from "Homologation", if the values is the same then put this values in firm column in worksheet 3, "Read". This code is from Button found in Worksheet 3.

I try this:

```
Sub Read_Click()

      Dim x As Integer
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      NumRows = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WUR").Range("A1", ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Homologation").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

      Range("A1").Select

      For x = 1 To NumRows

      Next

End Sub
```

With my code i try to find first values from the first column in "WUR" but my code work in Sheet 3, not in first WorkSheet where i want.

Comment: May i know comparing value is unique?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to find the first row with data?

Answer (score -1):

It might be because in

```
Range("A1").Select
```

you don't specify the worksheet where A1 has to be selected. If you therefore have currently another worksheet open, the selection will be made there. Try defining it like you did the line above

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WUR").Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: If you had another WB open it could still select in the wrong WB thats why you should use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`.